# trouble installwhen I install libpng in Cygwin64:configure: error: zlib not installed

Tags: cygwin, zlib, libpng

*# I first checked the lib if zlib has been installed like this:*

```
pkg-config --list-all
zlib                           zlib - zlib compression library
libpcre                        libpcre - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 8 bit character support
libpcre16                      libpcre16 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 16 bit character support
libpcre32                      libpcre32 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 32 bit character support
libpcrecpp                     libpcrecpp - PCRECPP - C++ wrapper for PCRE
libpcreposix                   libpcreposix - PCREPosix - Posix compatible interface to libpcre
```

but it did not work.this is error

```
86186@LAPTOP-RSLI617S /cygdrive/e/libpng-1.6.39
$ ./configure && make && make install
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
...
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
...
...
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
...
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... (cached) dlltool
checking for objdump... (cached) objdump
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
...
checking for zlibVersion in -lz... no
checking for z_zlibVersion in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib not installed
```

why?
I will be appreciated if someone can help me

I check the path there is no mistake

```
pkg-config --list-all
zlib                           zlib - zlib compression library
libpcre                        libpcre - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 8 bit character support
libpcre16                      libpcre16 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 16 bit character support
libpcre32                      libpcre32 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 32 bit character support
libpcrecpp                     libpcrecpp - PCRECPP - C++ wrapper for PCRE
libpcreposix                   libpcreposix - PCREPosix - Posix compatible interface to libpcre
```

Comment: have you installed `zlib-devel` ?

Comment: look inside the config.log to see exactly why the test failed

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the zlib packages are properly installed with

```
$ cygcheck -c zlib0 zlib-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
zlib-devel           1.2.13-1       OK
zlib0                1.2.13-1       OK
```

If both are OK, than you need to look inside the `config.log` written by `configure`
to understand why the test failed.

Please note that the package you are trying to build is already available in cygwin

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libpng-devel.html